# listtransactions RPC call

Tags: json-rpc

`bitcoin-cli help listtransactions` returns:

```
listtransactions ( "account" count from )

Returns up to 'count' most recent transactions skipping the first 'from' transactions for account 'account'.

Arguments:
1. "account"    (string, optional) The account name. If not included, it will list all transactions for all accounts.
                                     If "" is set, it will list transactions for the default account.
2. count          (numeric, optional, default=10) The number of transactions to return
3. from           (numeric, optional, default=0) The number of transactions to skip

Result:
[
  {
    "account":"accountname",       (string) The account name associated with the transaction.
                                                It will be "" for the default account.
    "address":"bitcoinaddress",    (string) The bitcoin address of the transaction. Not present for
                                                move transactions (category = move).
    "category":"send|receive|move", (string) The transaction category. 'move' is a local (off blockchain)
                                                transaction between accounts, and not associated with an address,
                                                transaction id or block. 'send' and 'receive' transactions are
                                                associated with an address, transaction id and block details
    "amount": x.xxx,          (numeric) The amount in btc. This is negative for the 'send' category, and for the
                                         'move' category for moves outbound. It is positive for the 'receive' category,
                                         and for the 'move' category for inbound funds.
    "fee": x.xxx,             (numeric) The amount of the fee in btc. This is negative and only available for the
                                         'send' category of transactions.
    "confirmations": n,       (numeric) The number of confirmations for the transaction. Available for 'send' and
                                         'receive' category of transactions.
    "blockhash": "hashvalue", (string) The block hash containing the transaction. Available for 'send' and 'receive'
                                          category of transactions.
    "blockindex": n,          (numeric) The block index containing the transaction. Available for 'send' and 'receive'
                                          category of transactions.
    "txid": "transactionid", (string) The transaction id. Available for 'send' and 'receive' category of transactions.
    "time": xxx,              (numeric) The transaction time in seconds since epoch (midnight Jan 1 1970 GMT).
    "timereceived": xxx,      (numeric) The time received in seconds since epoch (midnight Jan 1 1970 GMT). Available
                                          for 'send' and 'receive' category of transactions.
    "comment": "...",       (string) If a comment is associated with the transaction.
    "otheraccount": "accountname",  (string) For the 'move' category of transactions, the account the funds came
                                          from (for receiving funds, positive amounts), or went to (for sending funds,
                                          negative amounts).
  }
]

Examples:

List the most recent 10 transactions in the systems
> bitcoin-cli listtransactions

List the most recent 10 transactions for the tabby account
> bitcoin-cli listtransactions "tabby"

List transactions 100 to 120 from the tabby account
> bitcoin-cli listtransactions "tabby" 20 100

As a json rpc call
> curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "listtransactions", "params": ["tabby", 20, 100] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

However when I execute `bitcoin-cli listtransactions` it returns:

```
[
    {
        "account" : "mmfCt5VCQn4CAiv7EbJCuhUH1YbRSTB5Zf",
        "address" : "mu2agQWK8wrjiDeGaGx6kH6ndMAHZA1sPA",
        "category" : "receive",
        "amount" : 0.00594422,
        "confirmations" : 0,
        "txid" : "777aa309142a5ee282996344a67b547098b6beb7cf5f016dd2efc28970a1a4f3",
        "walletconflicts" : [
        ],
        "time" : 1417431126,
        "timereceived" : 1417431129
    }
]
```

The return format does not match the method's description, so which is the correct one? What am I missing here?

Comment: In what way doesn't it match?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz a description for `walletconflicts` is not included, for instance. Is it that the embedded documentation is simply out of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the help hasnt been updated to include the addition of the `walletconflicts` field. the only other thing missing is the `blockhash` and `blockindex` fields, and that's because  your transaction hasnt been included in one yet.